# How do you turn a tuple with one integer inside it into a string or an integer

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to turn something like `(600,)` into `600`, that is, take the integer out of a tuple. I get this when I define a function with an optional argument like `def foo( arg1, arg2, *arg)` If the argument which is passed as an integer to `*arg`, the result is like above, one integer inside a tuple inside the function.

```
def combine(city, country, *population):
    print(population)

string = combine('New York', 'United States', 50000000)
```

The rest of the `combine` function should give a string like `New York United States, population = 10000000`

Comment: Index the tuple?

Comment: ... what if people pass multiple arguments to `*population`?

Comment: This might sound silly, but why is the population argument a `*arg` in the first place? are there cases where you could get multiple populations? if so, you only need to deal with the first one?

Comment: Thanks! it worked

Comment: I am trying to get one optional argument vs, getting none

Comment: Optional arguments can be defined like this: `def combine(city, country, population=None):` If combine is not called with the population argument, it will return a default value of `None`. You can either test if it's None and then set it to another integer or tuple value, or you can change `None` to another integer.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and those comments about defining an optional parameter as type None is very helpful as I want to do things the right way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a value out of a tuple, use `[0]` as in `(600,)[0]`. That will return `600`. If you have it inside a function or variable, do the same as in `var[0]` or `func()[0]`. If `var` and `func()` return something like `(525,)`, it will return the first item, which in this case is `525`.
For more info on indexes and slices, [check here :D](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

To check the length of a tuple, use `len(var)` where `var` is the tuple.

And to check if it IS a tuple, use `isinstance(var, tuple)` where `var` is the variable you want to check and `tuple` is the class that defines what a tuple is.

EDIT: For getting an optional argument, you need a default value for that optional argument. Say you had a function that printed your name, but you could also input your last name too. See the function below:

```
def greeting(name, last=None):
    if last is None:   # check if last was given an argument
        print(f'Ayy, {name}.')
    else:              # if last was given as an argument
        print(f'Hello there, {name} {last}.')
```

Comment: Thank YOU!, I had this problem mixed in with other problems, knew about indexing, I was confused about the error messages!

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped you and might help other Python programmers like you, tick the checkmark to mark it correct. Have a great time programming :D

Comment: I am now getting errors regarding a unit test function, I get 'index out if range'  I'll post this tomorrow,  thinking not a conversion problem

Comment: If you got `IndexError`, it probably means the function you defined previously took it as `*args` and you called it with no arguments. You could put a try-except around it and catch the `IndexError` to check if you gave it any arguments.

Comment: Actually that's close but I had  'if population != ""'  just needed to know using tuple was the right way. i.e. 'if population != ()'

Comment: Looks like there's more than one way to a problem :D